# Inferring destination type from interface with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to implement some cross-cutting concerns in my application, which uses AutoMapper to map between different DTOs/message objects.

Say I have this:
`configuration.Map<MyMessage, MyEvent>()`. `MyEvent` implements `IEvent` (which is a marker interface with no properties). Is there any way to ask AutoMapper to map a `MyMessage` to `IEvent`, and have it infer that "oh, I have a mapping `MyMessage` to `MyEvent`, and `MyEvent` implements `IEvent`"?

This (invalid) example shows what I want to achieve:

```
// IEvent is just a marker interface with no properties,
// and is implemented by all of the *Event classes

configuration.CreateMap<MyMessage, MyEvent>();
configuration.CreateMap<MyOtherMessage, MyOtherEvent>();
// etc.

// ... somewhere else in the code ...

public class MyCrossCuttingThing<TMessage>
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    // ... code that does stuff ...

    public void DoThing(TMessage message)
    {
        // ... more code ...

        var @event = _mapper.Map<IEvent>(message);

        // Here I would expect @event to be a MyEvent instance if
        // TMessage is MyMessage, for example
    }
}
```

This gives me an exception:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

I've tried adding `.Include` or `.IncludeBase` to the `CreateMap` statement, but same result. Is there any way to achieve what I want, or is this simply not a supported use case?

Comment: out of interest, will it let you write `configuration.Map<MyMessage, IEvent>();`?

Comment: No, `IEvent` is only a marker interface and has no properties it can map to. And if I try mapping to it, AutoMapper just generates a `Proxy<>` instance instead, which I can't use, since I want to serialize the event after mapping.

Comment: Ok. You said - "have it infer that "oh, I have a mapping MyMessage to MyEvent, and MyEvent implements IEvent". The issue with this, I would have thought, would come when you have more than one mapping that implements IEvent, e.g.  `configuration.Map<MyMessage, MyEvent2>();` where MyEvent2 also implements IEvent. For that reason, I suspect the tool would not be set up to do this, because in the situation I just described, it would not know what to map to. That's just my best guess why it wouldn't work.

Comment: But since you expect that @event should be a MyEvent instance, it's not clear why you can't just map to that directly? e.g. `var @event = _mapper.Map<MyEvent>(message);`. Perhaps I've missed something in your explanation of the scenario as to why you can't / don't want to do this.

Comment: @ADyson - its just an assumption, but I imagine he may be having multiple classes implementing the same interface, and would want to create a generic method that would always return an interface which can later be converted to a concrete class.

Comment: @Nirman potentially, of course that's usually why we have an Interface. But the method where this is happening is void and doesn't return anything. And he explicitly says he expects it always to be an instance of a particular class. Also it's mentioned that the interface is just a "marker" (whatever is meant by that) and has no properties. So I'm struggling to see quite what the point of it all is.

Comment: @ADyson My example was a bit ambiguous, I don't necessarily expect it to always be a `MyEvent`. If it's a `MyCrossCuttingThing<MyMessage>` it should be a `MyEvent`, but if it's a `MyCrossCuttingThing<MyOtherMessage>` it should be a `MyOtherEvent` etc. I updated my question to clarify.

Comment: ok I see. Do you have an AutoMapper config for MyOtherEvent as well?

Comment: Yep, `CreateMap<MyOtherMessage, MyOtherEvent>()` and so on.

Comment: It occurs to me that AutoMapper works by comparing and matching object properties. Since IEvent has no properties, it'll never map anything, even if you could make it work. Possibly you need to get the real type of `message` and then do the appropriate mapping as necessary. You can still then pass it along somewhere as an IEvent if that's what yo need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this simple case you can use As.

```
CreateMap<MyMessage, IEvent>().As<MyEvent>();
```

Given that `IEvent` is a marker interface, you need also the concrete map `MyMessage`=>`MyEvent`.
If your real case is more complicated, you need `Include`. The [docs](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html).

Comment: Just to extend this answer, make sure to have the concrete mapping - i.e., CreateMap<MyMessage, MyEvent>(); statement. Otherwise, it will still give you mapping unsupported error.

Comment: Yes. It doesn't crash, but is doesn't work either :) (with the latest). Maybe there is a bug here.

Comment: I was wrong. I was testing with a base class instead. It works with an interface without the concrete map.

Comment: can you please update your question just to mention what worked for you? because, when i tried, I couldn't get the desired output without the concrete map.

Comment: There is nothing to update. I'm on the latest from MyGet, you probably on an older version.

Comment: This would work if the properties I needed were on the `IEvent` interface - however it's just a marker interface, so although it creates a `MyEvent` instance, it doesn't map any data.

Comment: Then you need also the concrete map after all :)

Comment: Sorry @Nirman, you were right all along, but we are on different versions and we don't see the same things.

Comment: yes, that's what the case I tried at my end :) the interface was just a marker, and all properties are inside the concrete class. that's where I guess you need a concrete mapper :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - no worries, yes, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way of achieving what I want:

```
configuration.CreateMap<MyMessage, MyEvent>();
configuration.CreateMap<MyMessage, IEvent>()
    .ConstructUsing((m, c) => c.Mapper.Map<MyMessage, MyEvent>(m));

configuration.CreateMap<MyOtherMessage, MyOtherEvent>();
configuration.CreateMap<MyOtherMessage, IEvent>()
    .ConstructUsing((m, c) => c.Mapper.Map<MyOtherMessage, MyOtherEvent>(m));

// etc. - will encapsulate in an extension method
```

By registering the mappings like this, AutoMapper finds the correct mapper based on the `TMessage` type and gives me back an event instance. Just as simple as I'd hoped!

Comment: That's what As does :) You've just reimplemented it with a hack.

Comment: Yeah, I tried using As, but it didn't actually map anything - probably because `IEvent` doesn't have any of the properties in the "real" mapping. I assume As would work as expected if the `IEvent` interface had the mapped properties as well?

Comment: I tested and it works. Instead of ConstructUsing you put As. Are you on an older version? It certainly works with the latest.

Comment: Oh! I tried it using AutoMapper 6.1.1 on .NET 4.5.2: `CreateMapper<MyMessage, IEvent>().As<MyEvent>()` and then `Map<IEvent>(message)` where `message` is a `MyMessage` instance, but all of the properties on the returned object were null. Is there any more setup required?

Comment: ... I might be thick, I haven't added a concrete map as well like in your answer now. I'll verify when I get home, but you're probably right - I've reinvented the wheel because I didn't read the docs well enough.

Comment: :) Sorry about that, but initially I tested with a full interface. The main purpose of As is to redirect the map. So the map needs to exist. Otherwise is just a sort of ConstructUsing.