# Automapper ProjectTo not mapping properties to derived types, although the mapping configuration is set up to only know derived types

Tags: c#, inheritance, automapper, transformation, projection

I am currently facing an issue involving automapper.
I am trying to map totally unrelated types, which works perfectly, except for properties of the projected class.  I am currently unable to map them to derived types.  (the information/data is all available in the source type, so it's not about EF and inheritence... that part was solved already).

Source/destination types

```
#region DestinationTypes

    private class A
    {
        public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
    }

    private class B
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    private class C : B
    {
        public string TestC { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion DestinationTypes

    #region SourceTypes

    private class D
    {
        public List<E> Bs { get; set; }
    }

    private class E
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string TestC { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion SourceTypes
```

Mapping configuration

```
var _cfg =new MapperConfigurationExpression();            
_cfg.CreateMap<E, C>();            
_cfg.CreateMap<D, A>();

 var _config = new MapperConfiguration(_cfg);
```

Version: 6.2.2
Expected behavior
I expected an iqueryable where the List Bs is filled with instances of type C.

Actual behavior
The List Bs is filled with instances of type B, instead of with type C.

Steps to reproduce:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestProjection()
    {
        int _total = 10;
        var _listOfD = new List<D>();
        for (int _i = 0; _i < 10; _i++)
        {
            var _d = new D();
            _d.Bs = new List<E>();
            for (int _j = 0; _j < _total; _j++)
            {
                var _e = new E();
                _e.Id = $"{_i}_{_j}";
                _e.TestC = $"C{_i}_{_j}";
                _d.Bs.Add(_e);
            }
            _listOfD.Add(_d);
        }
        var _cfg =new MapperConfigurationExpression();            
        _cfg.CreateMap<E, C>();            
        _cfg.CreateMap<D, A>();

        var _config = new MapperConfiguration(_cfg);
        //_config.ResolveTypeMap(typeof(E), typeof(C));
        //_config.CompileMappings();
        var _x = _listOfD.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<A>(_config);
        foreach (var _z in _x)
        {
            var _item = (C)_z.Bs.FirstOrDefault();
            Debug.Assert(_item.TestC != null && _item.Id != null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As would probably work here, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634493/inferring-destination-type-from-interface-with-automapper/45634815#45634815).

Comment: It does work using mapper.map, when I create a concrete mapper from the configuration, but the issue there is that it's not an iqueryable anymore, but a new filled list.  It doesn't work with iqueryable<D>.projectTo<A> (which would keep it an iqueryable).

Comment: The context that's missing in the question is that actually the source isn't a list, but an iqueryable.  I made a list implementation, but with a projectto which would suffice, else I would get all kinds of messages about Entity framework and inheritence, (And I resolved those allready)

Comment: Anyway a +1 for a fast and correct answer given the case presented in the example.

Comment: As works with ProjectTo. See [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/tree/master/src/IntegrationTests/Inheritance).